# Loading tile map into libgdx in android

Tags: android, libgdx, tiled, tmxtiledmap

I am a beginner to Tiled. I tried to load an tmx file in android but mine doesn't work. But when I try to load someone else's tmx file, it works. I think there's an error in my tmx file, but all I did was downloading the tmx file from Tiled. Is it the recent update that causing the problem or I downloaded the tmx file in wrong format or any other mistakes I made? Also when I load tiles from my asset folder, it creates tsx file. Is it smth to do with this?

This is my tmx file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<map version="1.4" tiledversion="1.4.1" orientation="orthogonal" renderorder="right-down" width="240" height="13" tilewidth="16" tileheight="16" infinite="0" nextlayerid="4" nextobjectid="13">
 <tileset firstgid="1" source="mariotile.tsx"/>
 <layer id="1" name="background" width="240" height="13">
  <data encoding="base64" compression="zstd">
   KLUv/WDAL2UAACC5AgAAAQC5cN4RAQ==
  </data>
 </layer>
 <layer id="2" name="graphic" width="240" height="13">
  <data encoding="base64" compression="zstd">
   KLUv/WDAL60KAJIFERugCUEANIDespyVpEACcyisEg0gFnqrHiO+dx6nOc1pdHiGxVMMniCzMCosQuIhJCtSl2XZAgtQjcXYVR7lTQ7yHs9xa6CgpTRIgIIJIDAyM5tcL3GKphrnfrqjjhy9cOUHSRsGmhhUf24wVd+jFogOL7j9iVJIReLwUC9z/5npcM6MTpqLo7owaMLCqDw20f5RlWTKpMqsSVuN3mt6FhF51iVg587kQlTxdYTqQXKCF64wjRuCi9AvKKcAqQ6XulmqN0zSb4YKGEwlSukvSEHMxnHfn9Nul9Y7U2KIVD+9KUioUPULPtU3e6tpiWm9B9VXczldu6jas6hs8RwcNFJ4x2BRO46krhWtLE0tpNU+tF4hjeNKdYRn7KI9NeWJomGRtPCllJpZp4Z8qtqjKU+ItrOaCzoVTJV5TBXySVU6q3lmdtWcqD/jGKX27H76j3p3
  </data>
 </layer>
 <objectgroup id="3" name="pipe">
  <object id="1" x="48" y="144" width="32" height="48"/>
  <object id="2" x="160" y="160" width="32" height="32"/>
  <object id="3" x="208" y="144" width="32" height="48"/>
  <object id="5" x="416" y="128" width="32" height="64"/>
  <object id="7" x="832" y="128" width="32" height="64"/>
  <object id="8" x="2224" y="144" width="32" height="48"/>
  <object id="9" x="2416" y="128" width="32" height="64"/>
  <object id="10" x="2512" y="144" width="32" height="48"/>
  <object id="11" x="2800" y="144" width="32" height="48"/>
  <object id="12" x="3664" y="112" width="32" height="80"/>
 </objectgroup>
</map>
```

This is my tsx file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<tileset version="1.4" tiledversion="1.4.1" name="mariotile" tilewidth="16" tileheight="16" tilecount="924" columns="33">
 <image source="mariotile.png" width="528" height="448"/>
</tileset>
```

Any help appreciated!

Comment: What is the error you get when running your map?

Comment: Could you embed your .tsx file into your .tmx file? Other .tmx files might have embedded their tilesets and your game can't load the tiledmap because it cant find the tilesets in your path?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is most likely the compression used by the layer data (`compression="zstd"`). Please change the "Layer Data Format" in the Map Properties to use zlib compression or even disable compression entirely (CSV option).

The Zstandard compression format was new in Tiled 1.3 and it unintentionally became the default Tiled 1.4. The default will be set back to CSV in the Tiled 1.4.2 patch release. I'm sorry for the trouble!

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer!

Comment: You're welcome! Btw, yesterday I released Tiled 1.4.2, including the fixed default for the tile layer data format. :-)